# Query expressions to Lambda Syntax?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

How can I change this query expression to lambda expression:

```
var dataUser = from cm in ConsumerName
                  join c in Consumer on cm.ConsumerId equals c.Id
                  join cua in ConsumerAccount on cm.ConsumerId equals cua.ConsumerId
                  join bd in  BankDetail on cm.ConsumerId equals bd.ConsumerId
                  join cpm in CardPayment on cm.ConsumerId equals cpm.ConsumerId 
                  where cm.ConsumerId == consumerId
                  select new { AccountNumber=bd.AccountNumber,CardNumber= cpm.CardNumber,  Name = cm.FirstName + "  " + cm.MiddleName +  " " + cm.LastName, Email = c.Email, AccountId = cua.AccountId };
```

Comment: With a lot of anonymous types. I recommend against it. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Standard comment: ORMs are not a replacement for SQL. If you need that many joins 'd be better off creating a view and or stored procedure and map the results. Or you should convert the joins to EF association mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, auto-converted by Resharper

```
var dataUser =
    ConsumerName.Join(Consumer, cm => cm.ConsumerId, c => c.Id, (cm, c) => new { cm, c })
        .Join(ConsumerAccount, @t => cm.ConsumerId, cua => cua.ConsumerId, (@t, cua) => new { @t, cua })
        .Join(BankDetail, @t => cm.ConsumerId, bd => bd.ConsumerId, (@t, bd) => new { @t, bd })
        .Join(CardPayment, @t => cm.ConsumerId, cpm => cpm.ConsumerId, (@t, cpm) => new { @t, cpm })
        .Where(@t => cm.ConsumerId == consumerId)
        .Select(
            @t =>
            new
                {
                    AccountNumber = bd.AccountNumber,
                    CardNumber = cpm.CardNumber,
                    Name = cm.FirstName + "  " + cm.MiddleName + " " + cm.LastName,
                    Email = c.Email,
                    AccountId = cua.AccountId
                });
```